# Martingale $Y_n$ does it converge as $n \to \infty$ proof or counterexample.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let $(X_n)$ be an independent sequence of random variables such that $P(X_n = 1) = 1/2n, P(X_n = -1) = 1/2n, P(X_n = 0) = 1-1/n$

Set $Y_1 = X_1, Y_n = X_n1_{(Y_{n-1} = 0) } + nY_{n-1}\lvert X_n \rvert 1_{(Y_{n-1} \neq 0) }$.

I have already established that $(Y_n)$ is a martingale.

So we have $E[Y_{n+1} \mid Y_1, ... Y_n] = Y_n \implies E[E[Y_{n+1} \mid Y_1, ... Y_n]] = E[Y_n]$

thus $E[Y_{n=1}] = E[Y_n] = .... = E[Y_1] = E[X_1] = 1\frac{1}{2} - 1\frac{1}{2} + 0(1-1) = 0 $

It seems that it does not converge though because:

$E[\lvert Y_{n+1} \rvert] = E[E[\lvert Y_{n+1} \rvert \mid Y_1,...,Y_n]] = E[\frac{1}{n}1_{(Y_n = 0) }+\lvert nY_n\lvert X_n\rvert\rvert1_{(Y_n \neq 0)} \mid Y_1, ... Y_n] \\ = \frac{1}{n}P(Y_n = 0 \mid Y_1,...,Y_n) + n|Y_n|E[\lvert X_n \vert] = \frac{1}{n}P(Y_n = 0 \mid Y_1,...,Y_n) + n|Y_n|\frac{1}{n}$

But then I have to consider what $\lvert Y_n \rvert$ is and so on but seems it could take on increasingly larger values as $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $X_n=0$, then $Y_{n+1}=0$.

By Borel-Cantelli, “$X_{n^2}=0$ for large enough $n$“ has probability $1$, so almost surely $Y_n$ is zero infinitely many times.

Thus, when $Y_n$ converges, its limit is (except an event of null probability) zero. But $Y_n$ is always a sequence of integers, so that in this case, $Y_n=0$ for all large enough $n$.

But it’s easy to see that $\{Y_n=0 \text{ for all large enough }n\} \subset \{X_n=0 \text{ for all large enough } n\}$, and the latter set has probability zero, by Borel-Cantelli again. So “$Y_n$ converges” has probability zero.

Comment: Wait I am confused, by Borel-Cantelli we have $X_{n^2} = 0$ infinitely often so then almost surely $Y_{n+1} = 0$  infinitely often, so $\{ X_{n^2 } = 0 \,\, i.o. \}$ has probability 1. Yet  $\{X_n = 0$ for all large n $\}$ has probability zero.  I don't understand the squaring of the subscript.

Comment: I’m using Borel-Cantelli to show that as, $X_{n^2}=0$ for large enough $n$. It implies that as, $X_n=0$ infinitely often. The key fact is that, as you pointed out, almost surely, $X_n\neq 0$ infinitely often.

Comment: So $\{X_n = 0$ for all large enough $n \}$ has probability zero yet $X_{n^2}=0$ infinitely often for large enough n. has probability $1$.  That reads like it takes value $0$ infinitely often and not $0$ infinitely often? I still don't see the need to square the subscript.

Comment: @oliverjones: Read carefully: the claim is that $X_{n^2} = 0$ for *all* sufficiently large $n$.  (That is much stronger than saying "infinitely often".)  The point is that $P(X_n \ne 0) = 1/n$, but to use Borel-Cantelli we need a subsequence $X_{n_k}$ such that $\sum_k P(X_{n_k} \ne 0) < \infty$, which is not true for $X_n$ itself because the harmonic series diverges.  Taking the subsequence $X_{n^2}$ does the trick because $\sum 1/n^2$ converges.  It's certainly not the only possibility.

Comment: @NateEldredge $(X_n) $ is an independent sequence so $(\{X_n = 0 \})$ is an independent sequence of events. and $P(X_n= 0 ) = 1-(1/n) $ Now $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-1/n) = \infty$ so by Borel-Cantelli $P( X_n = 0 \,\, i.o.) = 1$.

Comment: Similarly, $(\{ X_n \neq 0 \})  $ is an independent sequence and as you pointed out harmonic series diverges so $P(X_n \neq 0\,\, i.o.) = 1$ as well by Borel- Cantelli.

Comment: @oliverjones: yes, but what is your point?

Comment: @Mindlack That is was a confusing answer and there was no explanation for the squaring of subscript which I now understand but would have been more clear using the second Borel-Cantelli lemma. Also was mentioned above we needed a converging series to use Borel-Cantelli but that is not true as we have independence.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  The argument given in the answer provides a more explicit subsequence, though, and it would work even without independence.